# Is there a way to not autoformatting form in bootstrap

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4

here is my problem : I wanted to use bootstrap, but only for buttons.

Bootstrap is automatically formatting my form, but I wanted to do the css of the form myself, so I wonder if:
- there was a class in bootstrap to not doing autoformate for specific elements (maybe ?)
- or if I have to retire the form css of the bootstrap file myself.

Comment: Bootstrap has a class `form-control` to style the form elements. There is also `normalize.css` at the beginning of bootstrap css. You can remove component you don't like or use only css for buttons.

Comment: Thanks. Is it the boostrap-reboot.css file ? I didn't see the normalize.css file in bootstrap folder, but I saw the comment "Forked from Normalize.css" in this file, so I guess it is this one I can use.

Comment: Yes, I meant bootstrap-reboot.css. If you know scss it would be easier for you to manage css and select only components you need. Otherwise just remove all unnecessary classes from css.